# SerialPort port.open "The port 'COM2' does not exist."

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having a big problem with the `SerialPort.Open();`

I am communicating with an usb virtual com port (cdc), and it is listed as COM2.

It works fine in TeraTerm/hyperTerminal ect. but when I try to open the port in C#, it gives me the Exception `The port 'COM2' does not exist`.

I get the port name using the `SerialPort.GetPortNames()` function, and it looks fine when I debug.

I have tried to set the name hardcoded, but with no luck.

Now the really strange thing, it works fine on some PC's, and fails on other PC's. On some PC's it fail all the time, and on others it fails 10% of the time.

Even more strange it depends on the usb port used, some ports works fine, others fail (on the same PC!).

Could anybody help me please?

Comment: Driver trouble, they are often horrible.  Look for an update from the manufacturer, junk the device if you can't fix it.

Comment: I found a solution. Not a pretty one, but the usb driver on some PC's are just not any good.
Well I ended up with just trying open the port ten times, with 500ms delay between each try. I think the hole problem was the latency between the getPortNames() function listen the port as available, and until it was actually possible to open the port.

Comment: Man, that's yucky. I know your pain though. My home PC uses a monitor setup that relies on a USB connection. Any time the system loses power I have to spend 10 minutes on my knees replugging the USB connection over and over until it takes and I can have video. USB needs work.

Answer (score 6):

I've worked with virtual serial ports before. Oftentimes they aren't accessible as "COMX:" to some windows API calls, and you have to fully specify them. That might be the case here. Try using the Windows device namespace path for the serial device. For example: "\\.\COM2"

Another thing I've found useful for debugging is opening up a Hyperterm on the given serial port.

One final thing: For debugging your logic on systems that don't have all the hardware, I found this wonderful program called [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/). It is a GPL Sourceforge project that creates tied pairs of virtual com ports on your system. Whatever is written to one can be read from the other, and visa versa. You can either write an emulator and give it one of the ports, or just open up Hyperterm on it. Then give the other to your program. Testing with no cables or other hardware required.

Comment: com0com also has proper documentation and usage-examples!
Excellent find and well worth the time to check out if you do any kind of serial testing work!

Comment: I was trying to connect from a RDP session (on Server 2008 R2) to my local COM4.  Your suggestion helped me discover that the port is actually \\tsclient\\COM4.  I still had to trick .NET into letting me use that name, but eventually I got it.

Answer (score 3):

This error can be caused if the driver returns an unexpected "file type" for "COM2".

Try p/Invoking [GetFileType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364960(VS.85).aspx) and I believe you'll see the pattern. It has to be `FILE_TYPE_CHAR` or `FILE_TYPE_UNKNOWN` or else `SerialPort` will throw that exception.

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    string portName = @"COM2";
    IntPtr handle = CreateFile(portName, 0, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 3, 0x80, IntPtr.Zero);
    if (handle == (IntPtr)(-1))
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Could not open " + portName + ": " + new Win32Exception().Message);
      Console.ReadKey();
      return;
    }

    FileType type = GetFileType(handle);
    Console.WriteLine("File " + portName + " reports its type as: " + type);

    Console.ReadKey();
  }

  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
  public static extern IntPtr CreateFile(string lpFileName, uint dwDesiredAccess, uint dwShareMode, IntPtr SecurityAttributes, uint dwCreationDisposition, uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

  [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
  static extern FileType GetFileType(IntPtr hFile);

  enum FileType : uint
  {
    UNKNOWN = 0x0000,
    DISK = 0x0001,
    CHAR = 0x0002,
    PIPE = 0x0003,
    REMOTE = 0x8000,
  }
}
```

Also see [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/85af5fd7-ccd5-44f0-94d2-996db46a5a90) on MSDN forums.

Comment: Thank! I tried your code, but there did not seem to be a pattern between file type and the open problem.