# Unable to read a USB com port using GNAT Ada

Tags: windows, usb, ada

I'm attempting to set up a USB serial port using:
`GNAT.SERIAL_COMMUNICATIONS`.

I am able to open the port but when I try to set attributes of the port I get the following exception

```
raised GNAT.SERIAL_COMMUNICATIONS.SERIAL_ERROR : set: cannot get comm state ( 6)
```

Any ideas?

Sean

Comment: Have you checked this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317993/ada-gnat-serial-communications-behavior-on-linux

Comment: Hi, I did. Sorry should also also indicate OS is Windows 7

Comment: Wait, a **USB** comm port? Last I heard, only RS-232 serial devices were automatically set up as COM ports on Windows. Is this some special driver you are using, or a feature of Windows 7 I was unaware of?

Comment: The arduino device driver gets seen by Windows 7 as a COM port.

Comment: Ahhh. Well in that case, answer to follow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since what you are working with is not a natural Windows COM port, but an extra COM port created by a device driver, you may be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186395/serialport-port-open-the-port-com2-does-not-exist/3186501#3186501) (and in particular my answer to it).

The digest is that sometimes virtual COM ports aren't accessible to programs with the normal name. Before giving up on `"COM2"`, try `"\\.\COM2"`