# GNAT.Serial_Communication and virtual COM ports

Tags: windows, ada

I try to connect with GNAT.Serial_Communication to a COM port (Windows 8, from a console which is 'run as administrator') and receive the following error message:

```
EXCEPTION: GNAT.SERIAL_COMMUNICATIONS.SERIAL_ERROR: set: cannot get comm state ( 6)
```

This is pretty similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457070/unable-to-read-a-usb-com-port-using-gnat-ada), however my error is not solved by using "COM10", "COM10:", "\\.\COM10", or "\\\\.\\COM10" as COM port identifier. The error appears for all virtual COM ports (tested with com0com, and a FTDI RS232RL chip which automatically creates a virtual COM port).

Any hints are highly appreciated!

Edit 1: The connection works with HTERM (hyperterminal alternative in Windows).

Edit 2: Code snippets:

A) Call of GNAT.Serial_Communications:

```
...

Open (Port => Serial_Port_XBee_Pro_S2B, Name => Port_Name (I_Device));
-- where I_Device is the COM port identifier mentioned in the question.

Set (
    Port      => Serial_Port_XBee_Pro_S2B,
    Rate      => B57600,
    Bits      => CS8,
    Parity    => None,
    Stop_Bits => One,
    Block     => True);

...
```

B) Part of g-sercom.adb causing the problem.

```
  ... 

  if Port.H = null then
     Raise_Error ("set: port not opened", 0);
  end if;

  Success := GetCommState (HANDLE (Port.H.all), Com_Settings'Access);

  if Success = Win32.FALSE then
     Success := CloseHandle (HANDLE (Port.H.all));
     Port.H.all := 0;
     Raise_Error ("set: cannot get comm state");
  end if;

  ...
```

Comment: Please show your code! (Also, the working HTERM code.)

Comment: The exception is raised when the Windows API `GetCommState` function fails.  6 is the result of `GetLastError`, which means "Invalid handle".  So it looks like either the port wasn't opened properly, or perhaps it was closed after being opened.  I think we definitely need to see more code.

Comment: The code written by myself works under Linux. I then of course use the Linux implementation of GNAT.Serial_Communications. So I am confident, that my call is OK. I am pretty sure the port is not opened properly.

Comment: I looked at g-sercom.adb earlier, but now that I'm looking at it again, I think there's a problem in how it reports errors.  The above code calls `CloseHandle`, then `Raise_Error`.  I believe `Raise_Error` has an error code parameter that defaults to `GetLastError` (I'm at home right now and don't have the GNAT source handy).  However, if `CloseHandle` itself gets an error, that affects the "last error" returned by `GetLastError`, so the wrong error code gets into the message.  So it's possible that `GetCommState` is getting an error other than 6.

Comment: @ajb: Just checked what you suggested, but CloseHandle is not the problem. If I call GetLastError before CloseHandle, the error code is also 6. In the meantime I think it might be a 32/64bit problem. I cannot run my compiler with -m64, currently trying to chase up an appropriate version.

Comment: OK, downloaded cygwin64 and installed it with Ada. The -m64 switch does unfortunately not solve the problem.